# Why Safari is assuming ttp:// instead http://?

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

I have this piece of code:

```
function getTime() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/dtsbuz/business/date?exclude",
        success : function (data) {
            $(".mainHeaderb").html(businessNameG+ " Business - Dublin "+replaceAll(data, '\"',''));
        }
    });
    setTimeout("getTime()", 30000);
}
```

But sometimes in Safari the `/business/date` does not execute with `http`, but insted with `ttp` (losing the **h** in the beginning), and that makes the Safari ask the user with which application the user wants to open that link, as it is not a `http`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: jstl tags are interpreted on the server side, so I think it is not a Safari issue

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes"?

Comment: I have just installed Safari in my Windows machine, it does not happen, it is just happening in the Safari running on mac.

Comment: realUser404, it starts happening when the user leave the page and come back later, but just in MacOS using Safari.

Comment: Rightclick page in browser, do *View Source* and look there at the place where `<c:url>` did its job. Is the `h` really missing there or not?

Comment: that is what is being produced: $.ajax({
  url : "/dtsbuz/business/date?exclude",

Comment: So, JSTL actually didn't produce it. I'll reduce irrelevant noise from code to make it better focused. In the future, try to not make assumptions without verifying/excluding it first.